# ffmpeg - error when overlay text animation and video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this ffmpeg command to generate a video with fading text animation, this command is running fine with older version of ffmpeg - 2.8.11, but when I try to run the same command in another machine with ffmpeg version - 3.3.3, error occured :

ffmpeg command :

```
ffmpeg -i ./based_video/720/clip3.mp4 -filter_complex \
"color=black:100x100[c]; \
[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv]; \
[ct]setsar=1,split=3[t1][t2][t3]; \
[t1]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 1':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text1][alpha1]; \
[text1][alpha1]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=2:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=7:d=2:alpha=1[txta1]; \
[t2]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 2':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text2][alpha2]; \
[text2][alpha2]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=2:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=7:d=2:alpha=1[txta2]; \
[t3]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: \
text='Test Text 3':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text3][alpha3]; \
[text3][alpha3]alphamerge,fade=t=in:st=2:d=2:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=7:d=2:alpha=1[txta3]; \
[mv][txta1]overlay=x='300':y='300':shortest=1[mv1]; \
[mv1][txta2]overlay=x='300':y='400':shortest=1[mv2]; \
[mv2][txta3]overlay=x='300':y='500':shortest=1" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Error : Error marking filter as finished, Conversion failed

Comment: Upgrade. There was a bug with `shortest=1`. Use a binary built off a recent git master.

Comment: @Mulvya: thanks buddy, I was able to run the command without problem with latest ffmpeg version from Git - ffmpeg version N-89041-g91a565e20f-static